# Is this a Javascript memory leak?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, memory, memory-leaks

[image]
I have profiled my web application in Chrome Developer Tools, and came up with the timeline shown above. I'm creating and removing elements as of a hover function. I have read about this in [this article](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling).

Is this pattern indicating I have a memory leak? The Node count (green line) are continously rising, not dropping on internal GCs. But drops to zero on my forced GC. Is this common behaviour?

I mean, it holds a lot of nodes in memory, even though they are not present. If I check the **heap**, no references to DOM-nodes are present (no detached-DOM etc.), which makes me think this is not a memory leak?

What are your five cents?

Code below:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".btn", function(e){
    var el = document.createElement("div");
    el.id = "box";
    document.body.appendChild(el);
});
$(document).on("mouseleave", ".btn", function(e){
    $("#box").remove();
});
```

Comment: If it drops to 0 on forced GC then there are no leaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not seeing a memory leak in the trace you show from Chrome. The piece of information you are missing is that **when a garbage collection cycle is started it is possible for the cycle to *partially* collect garbage**. Let me explain.

I'm not familiar with the garbage collector in v8 but at various times in the past I've worked on garbage collectors. Garbage collection is a balancing act between freeing unused memory rapidly and application responsiveness. In interactive applications in particular you do not want to pause execution for long stretches of time to allow for a complete garbage collection cycle, as it would impact the user's experience. So there exist strategies whereby garbage collection cycles can be *partial* rather than *complete*. It seems that v8 uses such a strategy, because [Google's blurb on v8's garbage collection](https://developers.google.com/v8/design#garb_coll) states:

> This means that V8:
>
> - stops program execution when performing a garbage collection cycle.
> - **processes only part of the object heap in most garbage collection cycles.** This minimizes the impact of stopping the application.

So you should not expect that most cycles will drop the node count to zero.

Why is a forced GC dropping the count to zero? By inference from Google's documentation on debugging memory leaks, I deduce that forcing a GC cycle not only forces the start of a GC cycle but **forces the cycle to be complete rather than partial**, otherwise forcing a cycle would be useless for folks wanting to know whether there is a memory leak.

Comment: Thank you sir, this was exactly the case. Turns out it garbage collect some nodes and leaves some in memory. A full forced GC clears everything, which in turn means no memory leak. 200p to Gryffindor!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let's try to face the problem.

**Possibilities:**

How Javascript memory management work? It's all on reachability:

> 1. A distinguished set of objects are assumed to be reachable: these are
>      known as the roots. Typically, these include all the objects
>      referenced from anywhere in the call stack (that is, all local
>      variables and parameters in the functions currently being invoked),
>      and any global variables.
> 2. Objects are kept in memory while they are
>      accessible from roots through a reference or a chain of references.

http://javascript.info/tutorial/memory-leaks

So basically, JS will remove object from memory when it's unreachable. Let's try an example:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<div class="ourDiv"></div>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
$(".ourDiv").append(document.createElement("span"))
            .remove();
```

In this example i'm intentionally using class instead of ID, you'll see why. Our memory would look like this:

1. we have **html, body and div** tags in memory
2. we're appending span to ourDiv, so we have in memory **html, body, div and span** tags
3. after removing ourDiv, span element is unreachable so in memory we have: **html and body** tags

Let's modify it to be more similar to your code:

JS:

```
var newEl=document.createElement("span");
newEl.id = "ourSpan";
$(".ourDiv").append(newEl)
            .remove();
```

How is it working now?

> The element #id is an exception. It is accessible as #ourSpan, so it
>   stays in memory. Of course if you check it’s parentNode, it would be
>   null.

1. we have **html, body and div** tags in memory
2. we're appending span with ID to ourDiv, so we have in memory **html, body, div and span** tags
3. after removing ourDiv, span element is still reachable as it has ID set so in memory we have: **html, body and span**

**Conclusion:**

As you're setting ID to every created element, javascript will have it in memory even when you try to remove them with jQuery call. Probably it's because of mixing creating element with native API and removing it in jQuery. Try to check your `$.cache` size - if it's too big, that means jQuery is not properly removing objects.

But first of all - avoiding using ID for your constantly created elements should help.

It's more explained in: [Chrome Javascript docs](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling), [Firefox Javascript Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management)

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure on this, but I think the issue might be your mouseenter/mouseleave events not unbinding?